# Garbage collection in Javascript when Global variables are involved

Tags: javascript, html, audio, garbage-collection

So I'm building an audio player with html5's new `<Audio>` tag, but I"m declaring, initializing, and manipulating the `<Audio>` sequences all in javascript ([See example here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/05/13/unlocking-the-power-of-html5-lt-audio-gt.aspx)). Basically the `<Audio>` tag only allowed for one song at a time to be played and easily manipulated, so whenever "Next," "Previous," "Shuffle," or even just selection of another song was performed, I replaced the `src` of the audio tag with a new url, containing the new song.

Upon load, I declared the variable `song` like so:

```
var song= new Audio("url");
```

And every other following selected song was just an overwrite of `song` like so:

```
song= new Audio("new url");
```

The method has ended up working, but for each song instance, the event handlers that monitored things like the [range](http://html5tutorial.info/html5-range.php) for scrubbing and its attributes `max`, which determines the length of the range, and value, which determines where the index falls on the range, are associated with each previous instance of `song`.  I had to reallocate event listeners and reassign this attributes each time and after a certain amount of songs, performance does start to get affected.

My question is, even though javascript has a garbage collector that targets memory no longer in use, the instances of `song` all have global event listeners associated with them, so I don't think they are automatically deleted. Is there some way to delete them as soon as the song is overwritten? Is there a completely different but better method of accomplishing what I want?

Thanks for any help and advice!

Answer (score 1):

I decided to take a different approach to the problem to order to circumvent the garbage collection problem altogether. Though this isn't necessarily a direct answer to my question, it is an alternate, working solution.

I ended up simply reassigning the `audioInstance.src`, as supposed overwriting each `Audio` instance with a new one, containing a new url as a `src`. Initially, the songs wouldn't play, or certain parts of the auto player involving metadata wouldn't work, but I found [this](http://softwareas.com/audiovideo-tag-dont-forget-to-load-before-you-play/) link, which explains that you must first call `audio.load();` When you change `audio.src`.

This:

```
var audio =  new Audio(url);
addListeners(); //only need to do this once, since the listeners always point to audio declared above
var duration=audio.duration;
audio.play();
audio.src = newurl;
audio.load();
duration=audio.duration;
audio.play();
```

Instead of this:

```
var audio = new Audio(url);
addListeners();
var duration=audio.duration;
audio.play();
audio = new Audio(newUrl);
addListeners(); //need to do this a second time, since the old listeners will always be attached to the old audio instance
duration=audio.duration;
audio.play();
```

This helped me reach my desired final result and got rid of the garbage collection issue that was present with declaring multiple listeners for multiple instances of the `Audio` object.

Answer (score 0):

The variables will be garbage collected as soon as they're not in scope anymore.
The crappy thing about globals is that they are never eligible for garbage collection. My best advice is to avoid global variables and always limit scope to what's needed

Comment: Objects referenced by global variables become available for garbage collection when there are no longer any references **to the object**. So replacing a reference to one object with a reference to another object makes the first available for garbage collection (provided there are no other references).

Comment: Yes, but global vars will always have a reference since they're really window.someVar

Comment: @RobG Ok, I see what're saying. You are talking about cutting the cord between a global var and something referenced by a global.

Comment: Yes. e.g. `song = null` removes the reference to the audio object, so it can be garbage collected.

Comment: @RobG Let me clarify the situation. The older instances of song have their own set of listeners, listening to various things in the ui. When the song is overwritten, the listeners still apply to that older version of the song, even though there are no pointers other pointers to the song. But aren't the listeners themselves the pointers, and since they are global, don't they remain until you empty the cache?

Comment: @Wold—you've shown a simple call to the Audio constructor and replacing the value of *song* with an new instance (there is no example of that on the page you referenced). Listeners are on elements and should not stop an element from being garbage collected once it's removed from the DOM (noting that what *should* happen and what *does* happen may vary), unless you have some other reference to the element, e.g. if you're creating a closure somewhere. But you haven't shown any real code to determine that.